# Debugging CurrentAppSimulator.GetAppReceiptAsync()

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

While in order to debug [LicenseInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.licenseinformation)  we are provided with [WindowsStoreProxy.xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh779766#code-snippet-1) in which we can set the parameters we want, when trying to debug the [App Receipt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.getappreceiptasync)  - I can't find anything like it.

Where is that stored?

Comment: You are rejecting valid answers, the hangup is entirely yours.  You don't understand the process, there is no system.  You don't get system-provided data until *after* your app is registered in the store.  That egg has to come before the chicken, it isn't laid until the store server knows who you are so it can start recording real transactions.  You **must** create the xml file yourself to test your program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where are those stored, but as I'm debugging my apps, I just create app receipt samples ([like in this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases)) and then just load them from file like this:

```cs
StorageFile myFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///SampleAppReceipt.xml"));
receipt = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(myFile);
```

Once I've my `receipt` as string (the same as it would be received from store) I'm parsing it with either `XmlDocument.LoadXml(receipt)` or `XDocument.Parse(receipt)`.

Comment: @ispiro What do you mean by wrong receipt? I think that you either get the recipt or *GetAppReceiptAsync()* will throw an error/return empty one.

Comment: @ispiro I understand that you like to avoid this. In my case I'm just testing specific scenarios for app, these can be easily build as receipt is a template with not so many variations.

Answer (score -1):

Receipts are *generated* either by the Store or by Store simulator based on available data. In the second case you first configure the simulator:

```
StorageFile proxyFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(localPathToFile); 
await CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
```

And then request for corresponding receipts:

```
// Simulator generates receipts based on data you provided earlier
String receipt = await CurrentAppSimulator.GetAppReceiptAsync(); 
String prettyReceipt = XElement.Parse(receipt).ToString(SaveOptions.None);
```

Comment: No. [ReloadSimulatorAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.reloadsimulatorasync) Just loads the WindowsStoreProxy.xml, which does not include information lke, for example, PurchaseDate which is included in the receipt ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.getappreceiptasync)).

Comment: Ok. What time does it show to you? Is it different from your current time?